# FFMPEG watermark with filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use a watermark and apply Yadif using complex filter, but I cannot figure out how to apply Yadif with the following syntax

```
ffmpeg -i "source:" -i C:\logo.png -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -s 1920x1080 -b:v 4000k -minrate 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 11835k -crf 18 -acodec mp3 -ab 128k -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[out] -map [out] -f mpegts "dest"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated at the [support forum](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2971), use

```
ffmpeg -i "source:" -i C:\logo.png \
       -filter_complex "[0:v]yadif,scale=hd1080,setsar=1[b]; \
                        [b][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" \
     -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 4000k -minrate 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 11835k \
       -c:a mp3 -b:a 128k -f mpegts "dest"
```